# Homotopy classes of simple closed curves in punctured torus are in correspondence with those in torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces, geometric-topology, mapping-class-group

I am reading the book "A Primer on Mapping class groups" by Farb and Margalit and I have two questions about homotopy classes of simple closed curves in $S_{1,1}$:

1. Why is it true that homotopy classes of simple closed curves in $S_{1,1}$ are in correspondence with those in $T^2$? (I have read [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351166/essential-simple-closed-curves-on-a-punctured-torus-vs-those-in-the-torus), but don't understand it.)
2. Let $\alpha,\beta$ be two simple closed curves in $S_{1,1}$ that intersect at one point. If we cut $S_{1,1}$ along $\alpha\cup\beta$, we obtain a once-punctured disk. Is the cut surface a union of disjoint disks if I consider $\alpha,\beta$ as the two generators in $\pi_1(T^2)$? How do we have the punctured disk?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you cut a torus along $\alpha\cup\beta$ you get a disk. The easiest way to think about this is to consider the torus as the quotient space where you identify opposite sides of a square. You can think of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as forming the boundary. (Two copies of $\alpha$ are opposite as are two copies of $\beta$. ) When you cut along their union, you get the square.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Thanks! It becomes immediately clear right now! Do you have any thoughts on 1?

Comment: I am not sure there is an easier explanation than the one given in your link. Is there something specific you'd like help understanding about the explanation there?

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Just make sure I understand correctly. Since the punctured torus is homotopic equivalent to the figure 8, the only two simple closed curves up to isotopy in $S_{1,1}$ are exactly the generators $\alpha,\beta$ in $\pi_1(T^2)$. Since $\alpha,\beta$ are the only two simple closed curves up to isotopy, then we have the correspondence. If those are correct, may I ask whether $T_{\alpha}(\beta)$ is homotopic to $\beta$ or not where $T_{\alpha}(\beta)$ is denoted as a Dehn twist of $\beta$ along $\alpha$? I assume yes since Dehn twist is a self-homeomorphism.

Comment: I am sorry that I have found the answer. It's Prop 1.5 saying that the nontrivial homotopy classes of simple closed curves in $T^2$ are in bijective correspondence with the set of primitive elements of $\pi_1(T^2)=\mathbb{Z}^2$. Thanks for all clarifications!